# MySql 8 installation on widows: Database initialization failed, Empty value for 'open_files_limit' specified

Tags: mysql

I was installing mysql server for a course, and I can't install it, please help.

```
Beginning configuration step: Initializing database (may take a long time)
 
 Attempting to run MySQL Server with --initialize-insecure option...
 Starting process for MySQL Server 8.0.31...
 Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini

 - ---
 - " --console --initialize-insecure=on --lower-case-table-names=1...
 Using jemalloc.dll for my_malloc and ut::malloc etc.
 C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Empty value for 'open_files_limit' specified.
 Process for mysqld, with ID 7496, was run successfully and exited with code 1.
 Failed to start process for MySQL Server 8.0.31.
 Database initialization failed.
Ended configuration step: Initializing database (may take a long time)**
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjQnY.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXVz3.png)

Comment: I opened the my.ini file from `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0` then value of open_files_limit was empty so I changed it to 5000. But at the first configuration step the file is overwritten and the value returns to empty again before the `initial database` step

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem, in my case I don't need the newest version, so to solve the problem i've had to download a Mysql Comunity Installer old version 5.7.27 to install the Mysql Server 5.7. Give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I could finally install it by:

- Uninstalll everything
- Restarted the system
- Removed `[ProgramData]\MySql` folder
- `[Program Files (x86)]\MySql` folder
- Run the installer again
- Skipped installer update

And installation succeed!
I am running windows 11 and installed version 8.0.31 with `developer` config.